# $\vec Y''=A\vec Y , A_{n\times n}$. I have to find a requirement such that $\vec Y(x)=\vec Ve^{ax}$ is a solution.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

$\vec Y''=A\vec Y , A_{n\times n}$.

I have to find a requirement such that $\vec Y(x)=\vec Ve^{ax}$ is a solution.

I know that $\vec Y'=A\vec Y \implies$ $\vec Y(x)=\vec Ve^{ax} $ is the solutions vector such that $a$ is the eigenvalue, $v$ is a eigenvector or a generalized eigenvector , but whats about $\vec Y''=A\vec Y$?

Help please, thanks !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $V e^{ax}$ is a solution then (plugging it into the equation) you must have $a^2V e^{ax} = AV e^{ax}$ so $a^2V = AV$ and $V$ is an eigenvector of $A$ with eigenvalue $a^2$.